# Dynamodb lastevalutedkey format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I do have a table which has 3 lsi and 2 gsi along with partition key and sort key. I am querying with paginate feature.i am trying to build lastevaluatedkey with partition key and sort key but it keeps giving me an error that validation exception key is not in proper format. Do I need to pass lsi also in lastevaluatedkey. I am querying on one lsi index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not your responsibility to build a `LastEvaluatedKey`. It comes back to you in the response and you retrieve it, then pass it back on your next call.

https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-pagination/